# Using Python anonymous instance with __dict__

Tags: python-3.x, anonymous-class

I have the following code:

```
mock_reporter_obj = type('DbUserObjMock', (object,), {
    'uuid': 'test_uuid',
    'username': 'test_username',
})()

test = mock_reporter_obj.__dict__
```

I would expect the following result in test

```
{
        'uuid': 'test_uuid',
        'username': 'test_username',
}
```

But I get an empty dict instead.

Does anybody know what the problem is and how I can get the expected attributes calling `__dict__` on an anonymous function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`uuid` and `username` are just class attributes so they dont belong to the instance attributes dictionary (`obj.__dict__`) but to the class dict (`cls.__dict__`):

#### Code

```
mock_reporter_obj = type('DbUserObjMock', (object,), {
  'uuid': 'test_uuid',
  'username': 'test_username',
})

obj = mock_reporter_obj()

print(mock_reporter_obj.__dict__)
```

#### Output

```
{'uuid': 'test_uuid', 'username': 'test_username', '__module__': '__main__', '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'DbUserObjMock' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'DbUserObjMock' objects>, '__doc__': None}
```

The same happens if you declare the class as usually:

#### Code

```
class A:
  a = 9

a = A()

print(A.__dict__)
print(a.__dict__)
```

#### Output

```
{'__module__': '__main__', 'a': 9, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'A' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'A' objects>, '__doc__': None}
{}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that helps :)